# Retornar propriedade num relacionamento ManyToMany

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-2

Tenho um relacionamento `ManyToMany` entre 2 classes. `Campannha` e `Empresa`. A Annotation da classe `Campanha` está assim:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany( targetEntity="JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      name="campanhas_empresas",
 *      joinColumns={
 *              @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *              name="campanhaId",
 *              referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={
 *              @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *              name="empresaId",
 *              referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 **/
private $empresas;
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmpresas()
{
    return $this->empresas;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $empresas
 */
public function addEmpresas($empresas)
{
    $this->empresas->add($empresas); //ArrayCollection
}
```

A questão é que quando eu acesso o método `GetEmpresas`, volta como resultado isto:

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[609]
  private 'snapshot' => 
array (size=3)
  0 => 
object(Proxy\__CG__\JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa)[644]
  public '__initializer__' => 
object(Closure)[392]
  public '__cloner__' => 
object(Closure)[393]
  public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
  private 'id' (JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa) => string '3' (length=1)
  private 'tipo_cadastro' (JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa) => null
  private 'idMatriz' (JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa) => null
  private 'razao_nome' (JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa) => null
  private 'fantasia_contato' (JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa) => null
  private 'categoria' (JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa) => null
  private 'campanhas' (JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa) => null
```

Que está completamente correto. Eu queria saber como eu faço para acessar, por exemplo, o `id` ou qualquer outra propriedade acima. Tentei fazendo um *for-each* assim:

```
foreach($this->getEmpresas()->toArray() as $item){
        $emp .= $item->getId.' - '.$item->getRazaoNome.'; ';            
    }
```

Mas deu o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined property: Proxy__CG__\JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa::$getId

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O próprio erro já te deu a resposta.

> Notice: Undefined property: Proxy__CG__\JN\Entity\Empresas\Empresa::$getId

No seguinte bloco, você chama a *propriedade* `getId`, que não existe.

```
foreach ($this->getEmpresas()->toArray() as $item) {
    $emp .= $item->getId.' - '.$item->getRazaoNome.'; ';            
}
```

Acredito que seja apenas um erro de digitação, faltando os parênteses do *método* `getId()`:

```
foreach ($this->getEmpresas()->toArray() as $item) {
    $emp .= $item->getId() . ' - ' . $item->getRazaoNome . '; ';            
}
```

Comment: Foi o sono. Realmente após algumas boas horas de programação eu já não analisava mais corretamente. Assim que acordei eu consegui ver o erro. Obrigado